# EditText field cannot be edited

Tags: android, android-studio

My problem is that when I click in the EditText field, it gets focused, but the keyboard doesn't appear. So I can't enter anything in the field. What can that be?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SettingFragment">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:hint="UserName"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

      ...
  />

/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make you no other view overlapping the EditText field.

You can try adding the `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` to your activity declaration in Manifest.xml

[image: See Attachment]